# unable to sync database

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

I am unable to migrate my code. I created a database and a table in MySql but I had to uninstall MySql for some reason and when I installed it again, I changed the user name to root. Now it keeps saying

> (1045, "Access denied for user 'djanu'@'localhost' (using password:    NO)")

when I try to migrate. I named my user as djanu when I first installed it and I tried granting privileges to user root but the same message keeps popping up.

this is my code in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'applics',
    'USER': 'root',
    'Password': '531010',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',     
    }
}
```

and my code when I use python manage.py migrate or even runserver

```
(myproject) C:\Users\home\myproject\collapp>python manage.py migrate

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 342, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 61, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 263, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\home\myproject\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 193, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'djanu'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

Comment: You have user `'USER': 'root',` in your settings, not `'USER': 'djanu'`

Comment: Try the same using root user

Comment: Also you have different capitalization in your DB configuration. Make sure it matches the docs!

Answer (score 0):

This has happened many times with me. Possible solution will be to delete all your migrations from migration folder and then running manage.py migrate.